# SQL Query with CASE inside SUM not working

Tags: sql

A shortened query:

```
select t.Docket, t.TranType,CAST(ROUND(t.Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2)) as Net1,
CASE
    WHEN t.TranType = 'SRT'  THEN CAST(ROUND(t.Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2))  * -1
    WHEN t.TranType = 'DIV'  THEN t.net  * 0
    ELSE CAST(ROUND(t.Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2)) 
END AS Net2
                from trans t
```

[image]

But when I want to add:

```
SUM (CASE
    WHEN t.TranType = 'SRT'  THEN CAST(ROUND(t.Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2))  * -1
    WHEN t.TranType = 'DIV'  THEN t.net  * 0
    ELSE CAST(ROUND(t.Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2)) 
END AS Net3) OVER () AS Total
```

I get error: Incorrect syntax near 'SUM'. I just want a total amount adding up everything in Net2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a column alias in the `SUM()` expression.  You just want:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN t.TranType = 'SRT'  THEN CAST(ROUND(t.Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2))  * -1
         WHEN t.TranType = 'DIV'  THEN t.net  * 0
         ELSE CAST(ROUND(t.Net, 2) AS decimal(18,2)) 
     END) OVER () AS Total
```

I'm not sure that the `CAST()` has the effect that you want.  If you want the result as `DECIMAL(18, 2)`, then cast *after* the `SUM()`:

```
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN t.TranType = 'SRT' THEN - t.Net
              WHEN t.TranType = 'DIV' THEN 0
              ELSE t.Net
          END) OVER () AS DECIMAL(18, 2)
```

You *might* want to cast *before* doing the sum, but for an accurate sum you should only cast afterwards.